# Returning values from on column in a row if another column in the row meets specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to be able to get values from a cell in one column if data in other column meets criteria. Please look at the picture then read further.

[image: Screenshot.]

So I want to create one column to show all `SRaverage` values if column `naziv sloja` has text which says:

```
kora trošenja
```

And one other column to show all `SRaverage` values if column `naziv sloja` has text:

```
osnovna stijena
```

So I want to extract SRaverage values which are the ones for osnovna stijena in one column, and SRaverage values for osnovna stijena in other column.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `=IF(B10="kora trošenja";M10;"")` and `=IF(B10="osnovna stijena";M10;"")`?  Be careful! If somewhere in column B there is an extra space or more, then the result will be incorrect (for example, "kora   trošenja  " or "kora trošenja  ")

Comment: try https://exceljet.net/index-and-match & share if it works/not..

Comment: its not working, niether method, or I dont know how to use it exactly

Answer (score 0):

Sure. A couple methods come to mind, but the older ones are a little involved. Nowadays you can just use the `FILTER()` function.

You use that over other lookups since it gives you multiple results for the looked up value. They will ALL allow you to get more than one column related to the lookup value, but only for one instance of the lookup value. If you have multiple lookup values, you are out of luck.

So, filter. That gives you all the occurrences of the lookup value.

However, you ONLY want the one column not all of the columns in between. Again, lots of ways to do that as well. One of the also-rans, I will mention in particular, since it is a thing you can use for a HOST of situations including getting `VLOOKUP()` to "look left" which everyone tells you you cannot do.

That is to make a table internal to the formula that uses `INDEX()` to extract just the two columns of interest, the lookup values and the result values. Then there are no columns in between so you get only the single column returned. With `VLOOKUP()`, you use it for the second parameter, the lookup table, and have the columns reversed so that the one that is on the left of the lookup value in the "real table" is the second column in the formula's internal table so `VLOOKUP()` can get the desired result. You do that by using `{2,1}` for the column parameter in `INDEX()`, reversing their order.

Here though, the simplest way to get just the single column you need is to use a second `FILTER()` function wrapped around the first one mentioned above, or the "inside one." So the inside one gets only the rows matching the lookup value, then the outer one gets only the column you desire. People sometimes call this `FILTER/FILTER` (patterned after `INDEX/MATCH`).

But how do you do that? Well, the inside one you have to do a fairly traditional second parameter for specifying which rows to return. See how you tell it to match the lookup value in the lookup column? Blah-blah equals such-and-such? All unique and complicated? That produces an array of TRUE/FALSE values for `FILTER()` to pull the rows needed. You COULD pass it something like `{1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0}` to get rows 1, 4, and 5, but then you are doing the work yourself, right? (By the way, notice the `;` between each element in that array constant:  that goes DOWN, not across like using commas would have) So you give it the more complicated version like `A1:A9="a"` and let it find them all.

But for the second one, there's no looking through 100,000 rows for matches to do, just "Do YOU want the column, or not?" and you CAN easily type (or produce an array constant for that by other means) by typing an array of TRUE and FALSE values, or just 1's and 0's since they are easier. So you do:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B10:N24,B10:B24="kora trošenja"),{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1})
```

and

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B10:N24,B10:B24="osnovna stijena"),{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1})
```

Naturally, you can use all the usual ways to enter parameters instead of, for example, typing out ("hard coding") the lookup values. You can produce the array constant with a formula, several approaches for coming to mind. Or use the new `ARRAYTOTEXT()` with "strict" specified for the kind of array on a simple row of 1's and 0's or even more interesting values in the rows and maybe a complicated lookup to see which columns to include (as in someone selects them from, say, three `validated` (so no spelling mistakes) dropdown-enabled (so not hard for them and again, no spelling mistakes ruining things) cells and your formula looks up their column sending a 1 to `ARRAYTOTEXT()` in that column's place in the sequence... the world becomes your oyster. But the simple approach above works nicely for small numbers of columns. (Though using `INDEX()` makes that even smaller... just more complicated is all, but not much.)

So `INDEX()` could fit in here to make your lookup table for the inside `FILTER()` only ever consider the lookup value column and the result column, and then it could be applied instead of the outside `FILTER()` as well. Mix and match or just use the pure `FILTER/FILTER` technique.

Finally, remember how `VLOOUP()` only looks left, but `INDEX()` can reverse the column order inside the formula so it works instead of refusing you? Well, `FILTER()` only "looks right" too. Except... you can use `INDEX()` to take the lookup column, put it first, then just the columns you need in your output after it in whatever order you'd like the data returned, and present that to the inside `FILTER()` so in the formula, it is looking right, not left, and works. Bonus in that case, is that if you don't mind having the lookup value column in the results, you don't need an outside `FILTER()` because you only included columns you needed.

Again, the world is your oyster here, and many more variations on the theme exist.

However, the above formulas are absolutely simple and straightforward, easy to understand a year from now when the boss wants someone else to update it. Not you because you got promoted and can't be bothered with things like this!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).